# Getting "no such column: credit_limit" error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Trying to do a homework problem and nearly finished, but I keep getting this specific error.

The instructions are as such after creating the database:

After the six rows have been added, create and run SQL statements to do the following within the customerDB program:

Customer number 282 credit limit has been increased to $10,000.00, update the customer's credit limit.
Customer number 725, Deerfield's Four Seasons, is no longer a customer, delete the customer from the table.
Create a query to display all customer's names and credit limits for customer's with a credit limit of $10,000 or greater and a rep_num of 35. Order the results by credit limit in descending order.
Create a query to display all information for customers who's balance is greater than their credit limit.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('ABCcorpdatabase.db')
cur = conn.cursor()


cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customer')

cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE Customer (customer_number integer,customer_name text,
balance real, credit_limit real, rep_num integer)""")
print()
print('The database and table have been creadted successfully')

Customer = [("148", "Al's Appliance and Sport", "7550.0", "7500.0","20"),
                 ("282", "Brookings Direct", "431.5", "7500.0", "35"),
                 ("462", "Bargains Galore", "3412.0", "10000.0", "65"),
                 ("524", "Kline's", "12762.0", "15000.0", "35"),
                 ("725", "Deerfield's Four Seasons", "248.75", "5000.0", "35"),
                 ("842", "All Season", "8221.0", "7500.0", "20")]

cur.executemany ('INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', Customer)
print()
print ('Data was inserted successfully')

sql = """UPDATE Customer SET credit_limit = '10000.00' WHERE customer_number = '282'"""
cur.execute(sql)
print()
print ('Update was successful')
conn.commit()

sql = """DELETE FROM Customer WHERE customer_number = '725'"""
cur.execute(sql)
print()
print('Delete was successful')
conn.commit()

print()
print('Customers with a Credit Limit >= $10,000 and Rep Num of 35: ')
sql = "SELECT credit_limit WHERE credit_limit >= 10000.0"
for row in cur.execute (sql):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Please add the error output to the question

Answer (score 3):

The sql statement requires a FROM clause

```
sql = "SELECT credit_limit FROM Customer WHERE credit_limit >= 10000.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 3rd line from the bottom you made the mistake not to specify from which table you are selecting your `credit_limit`. Therefore you need to add a `FROM` clause:

```
sql = "SELECT credit_limit FROM Customer WHERE credit_limit >= 10000.0"
```